# Не работает TypeConverters в Room

Tags: android, kotlin, room

Класс БД

```
@Entity
data class ObjectEntity(
    val active: Boolean,
    val comment: String?,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: Long,
    val folderId: Long,
    val imei: String?,
    val name: String?,
    @TypeConverters(ObjectSettingsTypeConvert::class)
    var settings: List<ObjectSetting>? ,
    val stateNumber: String?,
    val typeId: Long
)

data class ObjectSetting(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String?,
    val type: Int
)
```

Есть конвертер

```
class ObjectSettingsTypeConvert {
    private val gson: Gson by lazy { Gson() }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromList(value: List<ObjectSetting>): String? {
        return if (!value.isNullOrEmpty())
            gson.toJson(value)
        else
            null
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toList(value: String?): List<ObjectSetting>? {
        if (value.isNullOrEmpty()) return null
        val arrayTutorialType = object : TypeToken<List<ObjectSetting>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(value, arrayTutorialType) as List<ObjectSetting>
    }
}
```

Есть ошибка:

> E:\SOURCE\android\appproject-android-app\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\ru\mydomain\appproject\data\db\model\ObjectEntity.java:19:
>   error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it.
>       private java.util.List
>   settings;

Чего я не вижу? Что не так?

Comment: попробуйте поставить аннотацию на весь класс, а не на отдельное поле. Если не поможет - проверьте еще импорты! Вдруг какая-то левая аннотация подтянулась?)

Comment: А ведь это сработало(ошибка пропала), спасибо, хотя часа 3 назад пробовал на весь класс выставить(только в тот раз конвертер указывал под аннотацией @Entity, а в этот раз в самый верх). Но все равно, я не успокоился) Что не так то?)) Работает или нет пока проверить не могу, но билд без ошибок..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно указать, что аннотация для поля:

```
@field:TypeConverters(ObjectSettingsTypeConvert::class)
```

Иначе она добавляется не туда, куда нужно

> Если вы не сделали указание, аннотация будет применена к элементу, выбранному в соответствии с аннотацией @Target той аннотации, которую вы используете. Если существует несколько элементов, к которым возможно применение аннотации, будет выбран первый подходящий элемент из следующего списка:
>
> - param
> - property
> - field

Так как в данном случае аннотация стоит в конструкторе, то без указания выбирается param (параметр конструктора)

https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/annotations.html в конце раздела Аннотации с указаниями
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: Да, работает. Эта особенность где-то описана? Почему то нигде такого не видел. Или это особенность идет из самого интерфейса TypeConverters -> @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD}), и из-за этого нужно конкретно указать?

Comment: @DuosDuo да, это зависит от `@Target` и от того, где стоит анностация, дополнил ответ